# Am I eligible for any USA work visas?

Tags: usa, visa, working-visas, freelance

I have finished my graduation in 2013 May and since then I took a year gap to pursue other interests including photography, writing and film making. As of April 2014, I have secured a job in USA for a video production company. They selected me based on my college degree which is in the relative context and my personal work. I would like to work as a non-immigrant and for 1 or 2 years. Is there any temporary work visa that can work here?

Comment: Your question is tagged 'freelance'--does that mean you'll be a contractor for this company, or will you be an employee?

Comment: "`I have secured a job `" - then why isn't your employer arranging your visa?

Answer (score 8):

There is. It is called ["H1b" visa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-1B_visa).

These visas are limited and there are only 65000 of them available a year (with some exceptions, for example additional 20000 available if you have an advanced degree from a US university, or there's no cap for certain research-affiliated employees like professors or doctors).

Unless your employer is exempt from the cap (video production company is unlikely to be...) then you missed the train for this year. All the quota has been filled. It becomes available on April 1st and is filled when enough applications are filed to give away all the available visas (which, this year, was within the first 5 days of availability).

Once you get the visa, you can start working on October 1st of that year. I.e.: if you got the visa this April - you'd be able to start working on October 1st, 2014. But as I said - you will not get the visa this year.

So, you will not be able to start working for that company at least until October 2015.

If your employer really wants you and hires a really creative immigration attorney - they may find other ways (like internship etc), but these are usually more limited in what you can do and how long you can do that.

Comment: Yes sir! I'am aware of the H1B visa. I want to know if H3 or P3 would be valid in this case. Since it's a video production (Film/Tv) Company, are there any other limited options for this field. And I want to confirm if I be eligible for the visa, I mean the company is fine with my experience, skills and are accepting me for what I have. But for the visa to be secured there might be many other restrictions on age, marital status etc. I have enough financial support and I have no plans to immigrate, hence I want to be sure that As I have already secured a job, will the visa embassy have a say?

Comment: @user13211 In the US you have to have the employer sponsor you. You cannot ask for any employment visa for yourself, the employer should do that. So unless the employer is willing to hire a lawyer and start working on this - you're wasting your time.

Comment: Thank you and Yes the employer has hired a lawyer and we are working on the available options.

Comment: Doesn't a B1 require the employer to prove that they cannot find a US citizen to do the job, so must import foreign expertise? Which does not sound like a new grad.  If the US company has an office in your country the could employ you there (on paper)< then "transfer" you to the US on an L1 (or is it J1? I forget).